# img-responsive in Bootstrap does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

according to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive, I want to make my image to support a responsive website by using

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

But it is not working.

Here is my code,

```
<body>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/myImage.png" />
</body>
```

The original image size is **284x191**

When I open a browser on 1920*1080 screen size, the image size is **284x191**. But when I open a browser on 1280*720 screen size, the image size is still the same.

I don't know what I did wrong to reduce the image size dynamically. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 the syntax is `class="img-fluid"`

Answer (score 5):

All you need is width:100% .
Using col-xs-12:

```
<img class='img-responsive col-xs-12' />
```

Or

```
<img class='img-responsive' style='width:100%;' />
```

Try this code

Answer (score 4):

`img-responsive` makes the `max-width:100%` If you want the image to be full width (even though it's actually much smaller than the width of a typical screen), you need to force it to be `width:100%`...

http://codeply.com/go/fDNOBhaQPS

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your Img tag with any bootstrap class. As I did as div with col-lg-4 class.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/36/gd/p036gdwj.jpg" />
</div>
```

or

```
<img class="img-responsive col-lg-4" src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/36/gd/p036gdwj.jpg" />
```

If you not wrapped with div tag

Link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MygbNO

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I realized that I was using bootstrap 4 (and not 3).

Changing it back to bootstrap 3 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know what version of bootstrap you are using. This is because the technique used to make images responsive keeps on changing from version to version.

I tried `<img class="img-responsive" src="<your-URL>">` and `<img class="img-fluid" src="<your-URL>"` but none of it worked for me.

For Bootstrap V4.5, use:

```
<img src="my-URL" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

Modify `<img class="img-fluid" src="<your-URL>"` to include styles, then it will work. The reason for this is so that it scales with the parent element.

You can read the [Bootstrap documentation on images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/images/#responsive-images) to learn more.

Comment: The version of Bootstrap is tagged in the question, the OP is using `twitter-bootstrap-3`

Answer (score 0):

use class="img-fluid" for bootstrap 4 version